# How to automate App review process with fastlane

Tags: android, fastlane

I am using fastlane to automate beta releases but I am wondering if it's possible to automate the review process?

So far, here is my configuration:

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Runs a beta build"
  lane :beta do
    gradle(task: 'assemble', build_type: 'Release')
    upload_to_play_store(track: 'beta')
  end
end
```

I've also tried

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Runs a beta build"
  lane :beta do
    gradle(task: 'assemble', build_type: 'Release')
    supply(track: 'beta', track_promote_to: 'beta', rollout: '1.0')
  end
end
```

Whilst this configuration does upload my `apk`, I still have to log in to the Developer Console to complete the *Review and rollout* steps - how can I automate this?

I want to run `fastlane beta` and not have to do any manual steps.

[image]

Comment: Hm, I know I pushed stuff to the channels directly with `supply`/`upload_to_play_store`. What manual steps do you have to do in Developer Console? Any input or just hit a button?

Comment: @janpio once it's uploaded to Google Play, I have to go to `App Releases` and edit the build to add a _Release name_. After that I have to `Save`, `Review` and then `Start Rollout to Beta` - I would love these manual steps to be automated.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce, but I successfully uploaded new releases both to "Alpha" and "Beta". In "Beta" it confusingly told me "You have a release that hasn't been rolled out", but as far as I understand that this is the current release from "Alpha". Possible that's true for you as well?

Comment: I only upload to "Beta" and not "Alpha". I too get "You have a release that hasn't been rolled out" - @janpio

Comment: Let's move this over to https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues so we can post screenshots to figure this out.